ExtJS 6.2 Disable Dates Before Certain Date in datefield Form Field
I have a datefield and I'd like to be able to disable all dates in the date picker before a certain date using the format YYYY-MM-DD. Can this be done in an ExtJS datefield?

Sure, use the minValue property, like:
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
title: 'DateField Example',
width: 300,
bodyPadding: 10,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
items: [{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    fieldLabel: 'Select Date',
    name: 'date',
    // Set the minimum date using a date string in YYYY-MM-DD format
    minValue: Ext.Date.parse('2023-08-01', 'Y-m-d'),
    // Optional: Set a specific format for displaying the date
    format: 'Y-m-d',
    allowBlank: false
}]

});
